# get class instance from require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Say I have a normal module

```
  module.exports = class MyClass{ }
```

The standard way to use it is like this:

```
const MyClass = require('myclass.js');
```

But what if I don't know the class name and the file name is a variable? How do I get the class from it?

```
const ???? = require(file + '.js');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering classes are functions "under the hood", and you can access a function's name, you can access the name at runtime. However in order to create instances, you don't need to know the naming of the class, within the required file, since you give it a new alias in your requiring file either way. Thus the only thing you truly need to know is the name of the file to be required.

```
// my-class.js
module.exports = class MyClass { }

// require-class.js
const MyNewClassName = require("./my-class");
console.log(MyNewClassName.name); // => "MyClass"
const classInstance = new MyNewClassName();
console.log(classInstance); // => MyClass { }
```

If you want to make sure you preserve the name of the class and expose it, I recommend exporting an object as a namespace. If you want to make it generic, you can fetch the name(s) of the exported object key(s) via `Object` helpers like so

```
// my-class.js
class MyClass {}
module.exports = {MyClass: MyClass};
// or module.exports = {MyClass};

// requiring file ...
const importedObject = require("./my-class");
const myInstance = new importedObject.MyClass();
const objectsInRequire = Object.keys(importedObject); // => ["MyClass"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable can be named arbitrarily, class name doesn't matter because it's entire module that is imported and module export is a class itself. It would matter if it was named export like `exports.MyClass = class MyClass {...}`.

`.js` extension is also optional, while relative path matters.

It is:

```
const MyClassNameDoesntMatterHere = require('./' + className);
```